# Does this have a name? DRY overloading?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, anti-patterns

```
public int foo(int x)
{
    int defaultValue = 0;
    return foo(x, defaultValue);
}

public int foo(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: If this is a pattern then you could as well call "i++" the "index incrementation pattern".

Comment: @Kim touche....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called emulating default argument through method overloading.

And where does it use polymorphism?

Comment: @delnan overloading = polymorphism

Comment: @Steve: No. Unless you mean "overloading on `this`", which would be a strange definition, would only work if overloads weren't decided statically but dynamically and doesn't apply here anyway.

Comment: Specifically method overloading - having multiple methods with the same name but different signatures - is (sometimes) referred to as _ad hoc_ polymorphism.

Comment: @Frank: Ah, yes. But that's not what polymorphism usually describes in OOP context.

Comment: @Frank: "ad-hoc polymorphism" describes *overriding*, not overloading. "ad-hoc" is used to disambiguate between type polymorphism (what people call "generics" in OOP languages) and overriding, not between overriding and overloading. Static overloading just isn't polymorphism at all.

Comment: @munificent: could you do me a favour and go correct the internet then, please? Overriding is just plain polymorphism. And type polymorphism is something different again: what most people call "generics". (And if you read the Scrap Your Boilerplate papers you'll find that "generic programming" means something rather different between, say, C++ people and Haskell people.

Comment: @Frank: Ah, you're exactly right. Somehow I managed to remember the terms all wrong. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

[Overloading is not polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400284/is-method-overloading-considered-part-of-polymorphism).

I'm not really sure of a pattern, except that it's a way to create overloaded constructors with default parameters.

Comment: I was under the assumption that static polymorphism is method overloading.  Anyway we digress.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4 this type of coding is not necessary.  Instead, use optional parameters with default values.  [More info.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/02/optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-in-c-4-and-a-cool-scenario-w-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

Comment: A bite of missing-the-question anyone? ;)

Comment: I wouldn't call the code in the OP a design pattern (not to be confused with a design principle). Patterns are proven techniques that can be applied in a set of scenerios. The code is recognizeable as an obsolete technique for new development, if anything that makes it an anti-pattern. Thus, the answer.

Comment: It's hardly obsolete, and optional parameters are a _tradeoff_, not a clear win. But the word you're probably looking for is "idiom".

Comment: @Frank shearar - point taken.  Good info on this subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316402/method-overloading-vs-optional-parameter-in-c-4-0

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Even in .NET 4, that style of overloading is still necessary in cases where the default value for a parameter cannot be expressed as a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 0):

"DRY Overloading" is a better description; polymorphism refers to inheritance hierarchies. I don't think you could call it a design or architecture pattern, either, since details at this level are details of implementation, not design.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is an example of how to implement default parameter values using a language that does not permit default parameter values.